# Business Software and Policies/Usage Hints

Tags: design-patterns, documentation, business-application, intranet

We use business software of all kind (CRM, ERP,...). There are lots of things to remember for fluent usage as keyboard shortcuts, company usage guidelines, colleagues hints, software manuals, internal documentation, ...).

My question: Is there a UX/UI design pattern for adding notices to screens of a software (e.g. on forms, on pages which require actions or user input)?

I'd like to see such addenum for business software to make personal handling easier and to easily deploy company knowledge as department policies, IT policies, personal notices, ...

Comment: A bit unclear what you mean with "notices to screens of a software". However I think https://www.userlane.com/?bl might help if you are the creator.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the famous or infamous pop-ups that Microsoft implemented to provide hints or guidance for users, which I am not sure if it is what you are referring to when it comes to design patterns that pop up when user input or action is required.

There are also software specifically designed to be overlaid on other software (generally knowledge management or data capture applications) that can be a jarring experience if their interface looks very different to the software it is running alongside.

I don't think there is a design pattern that captures all the use cases, so you'll have to be more specific.